# System.Object null

Tags: c#, object, null

I would like to know why when I go to definition in the class Object all the methods throw null like in the picture attached.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: They don't, not really. You're looking a decompilation of a reference assembly (expand the region at the top to see). The "implementation" of those methods is bogus, it just contains enough metadata for the compiler to figure out what the interface is. The "real" code glives elsewhere and gets pulled in at runtime.

Comment: According the the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-6.0  -- System.Object is the underlying base type for, well, everything. If you look at the definition for int (as an example), you'll see it overrides those methods.